# Previewing ARKit in the simulator with your phone

Tags: swift, arkit

In this tutorial the person preview's ARKit on their phone.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R8U8rGdMop4

Whenever I run the app it doesn't load the camera. Also, he somehow gets to preview the camera on the simulator. I can't seem to find the documentation on how to do this. It would be really helpful if I could view the camera through the simulator.

Answer (score 2):

You need a real device (with an A9 processor or better) with iOS 11 installed to preview ARKit.

In the video, he is using a physical device and the app Reflector 2 in order to show a preview on the screen. It's possible to stream live footage from an attached device with the QuickTime app as well.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I am still not getting the camera from my phone to work. I have installed iOS 11 on my phone but for whatever reason, the camera doesn't work. It doesn't work on the stock project that comes with Xcode

Comment: It's probably some other issue. Do you get any errors or output in the console?

Comment: Sorry for the code dump. This is the error

2017-07-05 12:25:59.843674-0700 artest[6949:1995145] [Session] Unable to run the session, configuration is not supported on this device: <ARWorldTrackingSessionConfiguration: 0x6080002839d0 planeDetection=None worldAlignment=Gravity lightEstimation=Enabled>

Comment: What device are you using? ARKit requires a device with an A9 chip or later.

Comment: I am using an iPhone 6.

Comment: The iPhone 6 has an A8 processor. Therefore it will not work with ARKit. (I have an iPhone 5 so I feel your pain.)